# Recursive XML walk finding empty nodes

Tags: javascript, xml, recursion

Using the following function

```
var data = [];
function recurseXML(node, path) {
    var i, nodes;
    if (node.hasChildNodes()) {
        nodes = node.childNodes;
        path += (path ? "." : "") + node.tagName
        if (nodes.length < 2) {
            recurseXML(nodes[0], path);
        } else {
            for (i = 0; i < nodes.length; i += 1) {
                recurseXML(nodes[i], path + "[" + i + "]");
            }
        }
    } else {
        data.push(path + " " + (node.nodeValue).trim());
    }
}
```

When I try to walk the XML [in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SReject/opqz399L/) it outputs as though there are empty nodes, yet there isn't

What's causing this, and how can I fix it?

Comment: fixed the fiddle link

Comment: Not sure what you mean by empty nodes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the whitespace between my nodes creates an empty text node. To fix this I trimmed the xml of excess whitespace between nodes, before recursively walking the XMLDOM:

```
document.body.innerHTML = (document.body.innerHTML).replace(/>\s+</g, '><');
```